# Excel: Lookup table name excel for a given variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have one Workbook with multiple projects. Each project has it's own sheet. In each of these sheets there are columns for order numbers ("OrderNub").

In another sheet called "MasterList" contains all of the order numbers across all project. This list is in column A.

I need a function or Macro that will search all of my sheets (bar MasterList) and will display the sheet name in column B.

Below is what I have in Excel:

```
Option Explicit
Function FindMyOrderNumber(strOrder As String) As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.CodeName <> "MasterList" Then
            Set rng = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
                FindMyOrderNumber = ws.Name
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                FindMyOrderNumber = ws.Range("A1").Value
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Where is the name column located?

Comment: The column is in row A (1) and the header is called OrderNub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Function FindMyOrderNumber(strOrder As String) As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.CodeName <> "MasterList" Then
            Set rng = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
                Set rng = ws.Columns(1).Find(strOrder)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                FindMyOrderNumber = ws.Name
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing

End Function
```

Assumptions:

1. Your project sheets us `Table` objects. If they don't, you need to edit line 11 to point to whatever range contains the `OrderNub` data.
2. If not tables, then your projects at least use the exact same layout. In that case, you could change line 11 to something like: `Set rng = ws.Range("C1").EntireColumn.Find(strOrder)`
3. The *code name* of the master list is `MasterList`. This is not the same as the worksheet name as seen on the tab. This is the VBA code name. I prefer to use that as it is less likely to be changed and break the check. You can find the codename in the VBA editor. For instance, in this screenshot, the codename for the first worksheet is `shtAgingTable` and the name - as shown on the tab in Excel - is `AgingTable`.

[image: Screenshot]

This is a function, not a subroutine. That means you don't run it once. It's meant to be used like any other built-in function like `SUM`, `IF`, whatever. For instance, you can use the following formula in cell `B2`:

```
=FindMyOrderNumber($A2)
```

Comment: Engineer Toast. I copied and pasted your code and it is not an option to run in excel.

Comment: You would put it in a cell as part of a formula. Since you stated that your MasterList uses columns A and B, the formula for `B2` would be `=FindMyOrderNumber($A2)`

Comment: Engineer Toast, I coppied and pasted your Macro and it is no a choice in my marco list. 

1) In every worksheet there is a table in Column A with the Header being in A1 and the order numbers under it.
3) I am not sure what the code name is.

Comment: I edited the post to try a bit more explanation. This is a function, not a subroutine. That means you don't *run* it. You use it like any other built-in function as part of a formula within a cell. From your question, it didn't seem like this was a one-time need. If you want a manually run version that loops through all of `A:A` and returns values in `B:B`, then that's pretty easy to add.

Comment: I inserted your code as a module then ran the function in Column B of MasterList and nothing Populated.

 I may be messing up on the range you were nice to make. Can you show me what the range would look like  (Row 11) if this "OrderNub" was always in column A of everyworksheet?

Comment: One option is `Set rng = ws.Columns(1).Find(strOrder)` and another would be `Set rng = ws.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Find(strOrder)`

Comment: Engineer Toast, This macro populated my order numbers. I need to populate the Worksheet name of the given order number from column A. My fault I should have been more clear.

Comment: That's what I had originally. I changed it because of your comments on the original post. Change `FindMyOrderNumber = ws.Range("A1").Value` to be `FindMyOrderNumber = ws.Name`

Comment: Engineer, I coppied and pasted the macro you now have in Excel and I am getting "Ambiguous name detected: FindMYOrderNumber.

Comment: You can't have multiple macros with the same name. Delete any old copies of the macro.

Comment: Engineer, we are almost there. I removed the duplicate macro and the function works. 

The code you wrote and it is only showing the last worksheet's name in Column B of MasterSheet. For line 11 I have     FindMyOrderNumber = ws.Name. 

If it helps I have all of these sheets being imported from SharePoint into it's own sheet.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the "last worksheet's name". Do you mean it's showing the name of the last worksheet in some file or the name of the last worksheet that shows the order number (which would only be the case if multiple sheets all show the order number which is totally different and not mentioned in the original question)?

Comment: Engineer, first I really appreciate your patience- I started using VBA a week ago.

Comment: When I run =FindMyOrderNumber($A#) then it displays the name of the worksheet that can be found to the right/end of my worksheets. Each worksheet/project does have different order numbers.

For example if I move sheet RIBank all the way to the right of the worksheets then Column B of Mastersheet will populate RIBank.   Or if I add a new sheet then it will say Sheet1 in column B. 

I pasted the code I am using now in my question for you.

Comment: I tested the code as @EngineerToast has written. It works for me.

Comment: OK, now I see the problem. I'm not sure how it go this confused. My last comment from 20 hours ago said to change the line that assigned a value to `FindMyOrder`. Instead of doing that, you copied the change into the line that assigned a value to `rng`. The code in my answer is still exactly what you need. Delete what you have and re-copy the code from my answer.

Comment: Engineer, we are cooking now. I was able to populate most of the sheet names. Problem is the columns are not always in the same number. I tried coping to column 1 and it would not work. 

Can you please tell me the range that you had that looked at the entire table?  I believe it was the very first range you gave me.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but I *think* what you mean is that the `OrderNub` field data is not always in column `A` which means that your sheets are not all setup the same. That means that this line isn't working: `Set rng = ws.Columns(1).Find(strorder)`  We need it to look in more places. If the order number appears by itself in a cell, we can do something like this to search the whole sheet: `Set rng = ws.Cells.Find(What:=strorder, LookAt:=xlWhole)`  If it's always in one of the first, say, 3 columns, we could do this: `Set rng = ws.Range("A:C").Find(What:=strOrder, LookAt:=xlWhole)`

Comment: My time investment here has gotten quite large. I need you to go do some research on your own if you're still stuck on something. If the code throws an error, try to figure out why the highlighted line is breaking. If it's not returning the right data, try to figure out why *and then try to change the part of the code that's doing it*. I can't teach you all of VBA. Come back with a particular question and an explanation of what you've *already tried* that isn't working.

Comment: Engineer. We made it work. I really appreciate your time it means a lot to me.